# What is the default setting value of SessionCookieConfig in Spring Boot, and how does it be set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-session

I am trying to configure my custom `DefaultCookieSerializer` in spring-session, the only property that i want to set is `sameSite`, and i want all the other setting use the "default" value. So I read some post, like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/87)

Here is some code snippet:

```java
    @Bean
    public DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer(){
        return new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    }

    private class CookieSerializerConfigure implements ServletContainerInitializer{
        @Override
        public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> set, ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            SessionCookieConfig sessionCookieConfig = servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig();
            // about the setting, see:
            // https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/DefaultCookieSerializer.html
            // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/87
            DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = cookieSerializer();
            cookieSerializer.setUseSecureCookie(sessionCookieConfig.isSecure());
            cookieSerializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(sessionCookieConfig.isHttpOnly());
            cookieSerializer.setCookiePath(sessionCookieConfig.getPath());
            cookieSerializer.setCookieName(sessionCookieConfig.getName());
            cookieSerializer.setCookieMaxAge(sessionCookieConfig.getMaxAge());
            cookieSerializer.setDomainName(sessionCookieConfig.getDomain());
        }
    }
```

Will this work if i don't set the properties in the implementation of `ServletContainerInitializer`?

---

I know that in application.properties there are some properties mapping to `SessionCookieConfig` fields, however, what is the default setting value of `SessionCookieConfig` if i don't specific it in application.properties and how does it be set in Spring Boot application?

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=something
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=something
```